# Removal of singularities theorem for J-holomorphic curves in non-compact manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Following the book by Mcduff and Salamon, J-holomorphic curves and Symplectic Topology, we know that every $J-$holomorphic curve on the punctured disk with values in a compact symplectic manifold extends smoothly to the whole disk provided it has finite energy.

Now I was wondering if we consider a non-compact symplectic manifold $M$ and a $J-$holomorphic curve $v: D^2-\{0\}\rightarrow M$ such that $v(D^2-\{0\})$ is contained in some compact subset of $M$. Can we modify the proof of these theorems to prove that we can extend $v$ in this case ?

I look over the theorems and it seemed to be that it would work but I would like see what other people, with more insight on the matter, have to say about this.

Any enlightment is appreciated, thanks in advance.